# How to avoid ChildEBP and RetAddr in WinDbg call stack?

Tags: windbg, dump, callstack

If one outputs call stack in WinDbg using `k` command then the output includes two columns ChildEBP and RetAddr at the beginning:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  
0151d9c8 55c59339 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48
0151da08 00e15b3a msvcr120!_CxxThrowException+0x5b [f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\eh\throw.cpp @ 152]
...
```

Given many crash dumps which I would like to cluster by the similarity of call stacks, ChildEBP and RetAddr addresses are preventing me from doing it: they are different even if the call stacks are actually the same just because of different addresses where DLLs were loaded.

It is clear that such things can be removed by some simple text processing, but may be there is some command in WinDbg which allows showing call stacks without ChildEBP and RetAddr like that:

```
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x48
msvcr120!_CxxThrowException+0x5b [f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtw32\eh\throw.cpp @ 152]
...
```

?

Comment: [`kc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do what you want. It displays a *clean* stack track.

Comment: @SeanCline, thanks that works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Sean Cline](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020072/sean-cline) in the comments already, [`kc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) displays a **clean** stack.